# What is the Difference Between 'Protected Friend' and 'Private Protected'?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am currently relearning VB.NET coming from a C# and VB6 background and I have come across the 'Protected Friend' and 'Private Protected' access modifier combinations described in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/dim-statement).

However, I am having trouble understanding the difference between the two combinations and how you can have something that is declared both private and protected.

Is there a an open-source project that demonstrates the difference? I think it would be easier to understand the difference(s) in a real-world situation.

Comment: "Protected Freind" doesn't exist. "Protected Friend" does...

Comment: Try reading [Access Levels in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/access-levels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an OR vs AND difference:

**Protected Friend** specifies that the element can be accessed either from within the class **or** from derived classes **or** from within the same assembly.

**Private Protected** specifies that the element can be accessed only from within the same class, as well as from derived classes, (**and** = *only if*) found **in the same assembly** as the containing class.

See [Access Levels in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/access-levels).